# Parse objectID in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, objectid

I am trying to load a page of information about an Object in Swift from Parse. The code given allows you to retrieve the entire class at once. But how do I would I retrieve the ObjectID without accessing the dashboard on Parse?

This code is from Parse

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
  (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
    println(gameScore)
  } else {
    println(error)
  }
}
```

Everything is straight forward but I still don't know how to get randomly generated ObjectID.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to query all objects and list its Ids, for example:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            //list of Ids
            for object in objects {
                objectIds.append(object.objectId as String)
            }
        } else {
            println("\(error)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: No I want to just pull one Row from the PFObject. For instance if I clicked on a Chevy Camaro Icon it would pull the number of tires, number of doors, number of lights etc. Just for that car and not for all of the other cars in that class of cars. I hope I said that the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have 2 separate classes in your parse dashboard.
As per your example one for carTypes and another class carDetails with a pointer to carTypes.

the when you click on a car, you can query the carDetails class using objectId from the carTypes.

for example

```
    // you have to give this object some value when you click on a button or    cell..etc
    var selectedCar : PFObject?

//in the query i didn't use selectedCar.objectId because i am using pointers to the carType class so parse will get the objectId for you

        let query = PFQuery(className: "carDetails")
        query.whereKey("carType", equalTo: selectedCar)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: [PFObject]?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
        some code here
        }
                    })
```

i hope this clarifies